# multiple 301 redirects htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I recently changed the filename of some of my pages. For example

work1.html to acn-website.html

work2.html to inkdrawn-website.html

etc.

I currently have the following in my htaccess file;

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^fullfatdesigns\.co.uk$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.fullfatdesigns.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L] 

ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.php  
ErrorDocument 403 /error/403.php
```

How do I go about inserting multiple 301 re-directs into my existing file?

Thank you
Wayne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add

```
RewriteRule oldPage\.html http://www.fullfatdesigns.co.uk/newPage.html [R=301,L]
```

after `RewriteEngine on` for every redirect.